# Reputation on unaccept wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

What happened is this. I answered a question and the question got **3** upvotes. Obviously, `3*10 = 30`. Then the answer got accepted, `30 + 15 = 45`. The next day the answer was unaccepted resulting in a loss of 15 reputation, `45 - 15 = 30`. Now the reputation tab says I have only gotten 15 points for the question. Here is the image:

[image: reputation image]

(I very well know that a reputation recalc would fix this, but I wanted to report it anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** These changes are now live on meta, and will begin rolling out to the rest of the network soon.

---

Yep, this is a bug, we won't be fixing it though (not directly, read on...)

We're working on something right now that encompasses reputation history as a whole, hopefully you'll like the results.  This "thing" will resolve the vast majority of reputation bugs that have been filed here on meta.  We'll be posting the details here on meta when it's further along, stay tuned.

I'll leave this open, as it is a bug and on our radar, but it'll stick around until the long-term solution is in place.

Comment: Hooray!  Will deleting a downvoted answer adjust your rep accordingly, after this new fix?

Comment: @Adam - stay tuned :)

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation when it's implemented... sounds interesting